# DB locking during select, update, insert and delete

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, indexing

I want to understand how locking works in SQL Server (2005/2008) during select, update, insert and delete operations. Specifically, I want to know if Indexes have anything to do with locking. I mean, having a primary key helping in locking a row rather than entire table etc., Can someone suggest some articles?

Thanks,
Gopal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server 2008, you can start with [Locking and Row Versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187101.aspx), and [Customizing Locking for an Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189076.aspx).

You can control locking granularity using CREATE INDEX..., ALTER INDEX..., CREATE TABLE..., and ALTER TABLE.... See, for example, the syntax for [CREATE INDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx), and search that page for the options ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS and ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS.